# Media queries first or less?

Tags: css, responsive-design, less, media-queries

I have completed html and css and now i want to pass another step.So should I learn responsive design with media queries first or learning Less for CSS then I pass for media queries?

Answer (score 3):

Less is just a smarter way of generating CSS. I think you should learn everything CSS has to offer before jumping to a language that just generates CSS. I will give you two good reasons for that:

1. You can do anything with CSS that you could do with LESS. You can't do responsive design with Less if you don't know media queries.
2. Knowing what is happening under the hood will ease the learning of a preprocessor language (Less, Sass, etc) later, as you will have a better understanding of the bigger picture.

Comment: So I have to learn responsive with media queries first ?

Comment: You don't have to, just as you don't have to trust some dude on the internet :)  But yes, I think you should learn media queries first.

Comment: Thank you Hugo :))

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that media queries are easy enough to pick up alongside of a library like SASS/LESS. Responsive design is more about the concept of giving your elements dynamic values than static ones. But, don't let learning one inhibit you from learning the other. If you already have a solid understanding of css, jump in and do both at the same time. It's not like you can't go back and check out what you've written in plain css after it has been compiled.

cheers mate!